# NSFetchedResultsController starts with a nil object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have `UICollectionViewController` with an `NSFetchedResultsController`, implemented like so:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    // 0 = get all results.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.sortKey ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ sortDescriptor ];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    if (self.predicate) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:self.predicate];
    }

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

The `UICollectionViewController` has the following methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

# pragma mark - UIControllerViewDelegate
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FullPageCollectionViewCell *cell = (FullPageCollectionViewCell*)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self handleImageForEntity:event forCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = event.title;
    cell.textLabel.text = event.summary;
    cell.timeLabel.text = [event.updatedAt timeAgo];

    return cell;
}
```

When there are no entities to be fetched, the FRC still returns an object with all of its properties set to `nil` (a faulted object), and then the `UICollectionView` renders a cell with everything (`cell.titleLabel.text`, etc) set to `nil`. Why is the FRC returning this object if there are no entities yet? How can I prevent it from doing so?

In this case, the particular entity that I'm fetching inherits from an abstract entity, if that has any effect.

Comment: Remove the cache (should you be using a cache? have you changed the fetch request?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion – I've tried it without the cache but am still having the issue.

Comment: It suggests you have an empty entity instance in the data store. Have you deleted and reinstalled the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of digging, I finally found the solution. In the end it had nothing to do with `NSFetchedResultsController` but had everything to do with RestKit and its object mappings, which is what I was using to map JSON data from my API to Core Data entities. The particular issue here was specific to how I had things setup, but hopefully it can provide insight to others with a similar problem.

In my API, there is a `/user` endpoint which returns information about the currently authenticated user (name, profile image, etc):

```
{
   "name": "Frank",
   "image": "https://images.site.com/image.jpg"
}
```

When the user logs in, this endpoint is hit to get their information, and RestKit performs the appropriate mapping.

There is an additional endpoint, `/user/bookmarked`, which returns information about items (Events) the user has bookmarked, like so:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Very interesting"
    }
]
```

In Core Data, I have a `CurrentUser` entity, which the `/user` endpoint maps to, and the `CurrentUser` has a `bookmarked` relationship to many `Events`; this relationship is mapped to the `/user/bookmarked` endpoint.

So my RestKit mappings were setup like so:

```
RKEntityMapping *currentUserMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CurrentUser" inManagedObjectStore:mos];
[currentUserMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userMappings];
currentUserMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[CurrentUser class] pathPattern:@"/user" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
RKResponseDescriptor *currentUserResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:currentUserMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/user" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:currentUserResponseDescriptor];

NSString* bookmarkedPath = @"/user/bookmarked";
// Setup the relationship which maps these events to the CurrentUser's "bookmarked" relationship.
RKRelationshipMapping *bookmarkedRelationshipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"bookmarked" withMapping:eventMapping];
[currentUserMapping addPropertyMapping:bookmarkedRelationshipMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *bookmarkedResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:currentUserMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:bookmarkedPath keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:bookmarkedResponseDescriptor];

RKRoute *bookmarkedRoute = [RKRoute routeWithName:kArgosBookmarkedStream pathPattern:bookmarkedPath method:RKRequestMethodGET];
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:bookmarkedRoute];
```

The problem is that `bookmarked` relationship is being added to the same `CurrentUser` mapping used for `/user`. So when I was hitting the `/user` endpoint, RestKit was applying both the `CurrentUser` mapping (and successfully finding the name, image, etc) but also trying to apply the `bookmarked` mapping. The response that `/user` provides does not have any of the bookmarked information (id, title, etc) so RestKit just fills in `nil` for those values.

The solution was to keep the `CurrentUser` and `bookmarked` mapping separate, so I created a new mapping specifically for the `CurrentUser`'s `bookmarked` relationship:

```
NSString* bookmarkedPath = @"/user/bookmarked";
RKEntityMapping *currentUserBookmarkedMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CurrentUser" inManagedObjectStore:mos];
[currentUserBookmarkedMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:userMappings];
currentUserBookmarkedMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userId" ];
// Setup the relationship which maps these events to the CurrentUser's "bookmarked" relationship.
RKRelationshipMapping *bookmarkedRelationshipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"bookmarked" withMapping:eventMapping];
[currentUserBookmarkedMapping addPropertyMapping:bookmarkedRelationshipMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *bookmarkedResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:currentUserBookmarkedMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:bookmarkedPath keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:bookmarkedResponseDescriptor];

RKRoute *bookmarkedRoute = [RKRoute routeWithName:kArgosBookmarkedStream pathPattern:bookmarkedPath method:RKRequestMethodGET];
[objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:bookmarkedRoute];
```

After that, everything was fine!